# what is better when calling/navigating html pages

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

what is better when calling/navigating webpages

A multiple href with calling header and footer inside its file and has own data inside its

```
<div id="content"><div>
<a href="info.php">INFO</a>
```

or

Having a single index.php that only call html pages to be displayed inside its `<div id="content">`
maybe by the use of ajax or jquery.load ? or other techniques,  like `index.php?nav=info`

what is the best practice?

thanks

Comment: The question seems quite general. Do you have a particular project in regard to your asking?

Comment: i.e a student portal wherein stud grades, info are in there i dont want them to be shown by the use of refreshing the page, but I want to know the suggestion of other programmers

Answer (score 0):

Go for the common header footer approach. As in, have individual pages which all fetch the header & footer content from a common location.
Pros:

- Having separate HTML pages will give you an advantage of having friendly REST URLs like /About, /Contact, etc. This way the overhead of reading the query string and displaying the appropriate page content can also be avoided
- Easy to maintain (Any change that comes up in the header or footer needs to be made only at one place)
- reduced file sizes

Comment: so i do have to use $_SESSIONS for the logged in privileges

Comment: Yes! That is how you can serve protected content (custom markup or protected pages) to the logged in users.

Answer (score 0):

There are various ways :

1. Using Ajax to load them  Using Iframe
2. Using XSLT to create the pages based on an XML
3. Using JavaScript to generate the header and
       footer by (CreateElement function)
4. Use JavaScript to generate two
           mentioned Html tages (   and  INFO) and setting the href by JavaScript)
5. Generating header and footer in Server side (Bad solution)
6. Using Ajax to append some HTML tags to the 2 mentioned tag.

So, which one is your choice?